# Is there a way to limit access to Windows or Linux file shares to certain dates and times?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, shares

Is it possible to limit the dates and times a share is available?  For example, I may have a group that needs a share, one to be visible, at certain dates and times.  I do not mean smb or nfs connectivity between Linux and Windows.  I am asking if either OS is capable for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

While possibly a [partial] duplicate of [Restrict file server (CIFS) access by time of day](https://serverfault.com/q/343245/2321), there is a possible workaround for what you are asking.

***IF*** you are running the share(s) from a Linux machine, you *could* add crontab entries that enable and disable the CIFS and NFS services during certain times of the day.

<sup><sub>(It may be possible to disable CIFS on Windows using the scheduler, but I've not used the Windows scheduler much.)</sub></sup>

There are problems with this workaround, of course - not limited to:

- if you're in the middle of a save/copy, files will get corrupted
- remapping network shares can be painful when connectivity is lost (stale NFS handles, and the like)

You *might* be able to time-restrict when users can login to the domain - but I am unsure if this is handled natively in AD, OpenLDAP, FreeIPA, etc.