# Is there a way to have a network drive accessible on limited time?

Tags: windows, network-attached-storage, mappeddrive

I'm new to networking. 
Is there a way to have the PC in the office (40-50 computers) to have like a time-based access to the NAS drive? (Note that we would have the NAS drive's folders be mapped on each PC) 
Example: 
Users can only access the mapped drive between 9am - 5pm. 
We wanted a way to control the files/folders in the NAS drive (uploading, downloading, editing, printing, etc..) and one way to do it (in my own understanding) is to restrict the users from accessing the mapped drive in a given time. 
I'm also open for options as well. 
Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Sure. Please tell us all the features and options of your “NAS.”

Comment: Well we're currently using Synology NAS and already asked them about this and they dont have this option.. We're also planning to buy one but not sure what to buy to have this kind of option.. And we also thought that maybe a dedicated server would solve this.. Just not sure where to start

Comment: If it’s not possible with the NAS, then it’s not possible. It’s dependent on the feature set.  As it stands, there is nothing that can be answered about your question. There are ways to do it with a Windows server.

Comment: We're open for that option as well.. So how do we do it on a windows server?

Comment: On a *nix box I'd simply have a cron job start/stop the Samba (or NFS or whatever) service at the appropriate times.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the terms..

Comment: Here are suggestions: https://serverfault.com/questions/343245/restrict-file-server-cifs-access-by-time-of-day although I can think of other ways as well, better combining the ideas presented.

Comment: Will try and check on this and see if it works well.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script to modify the top level folder permissions to a different group that those users aren't a member of. That way the drive mapping will stay intact but they just won't have access to the folder. Run the script at the times you indicate.

Comment: This is also an interesting idea.. Do you have a sample script where we could use? Sorry really new in this kind of thing..

Comment: What OS are you dealing with here and what filesystem?

Comment: the computer over there are windows 7 and windows 10 (around 40-50 computers).. I dont think they have a dedicated server yet but we're considering of having one installed Windows Server..